# How to get and append most recent messages from server using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on my first simple chat application and this issue has me stuck. I know what I'm trying to do, but I end up overthinking it.

Basically, I have this heroku server going:

http://tiy-fee-rest.herokuapp.com/collections/blabberTalk

Whenever someone sends a message, it is added to this array.

**My Issue:**

I have it on a set interval so that every 2 seconds, it runs the getNewestMessages function. When this setInterval is working and someone sends a message, it will keep appending the last message they sent every 2 seconds. If I disable the setInterval and simply call the getNewestMessages function myself in a separate browser tab, this doesn't seem to happen. **I want to make it so that the most recently sent message isn't constantly re-appended to the DOM when the setInterval is active.**

This is the function I'm using to check for recent messages. It's pretty bloated, sorry about that:

```
  getNewestMessages: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: http://tiy-fee-rest.herokuapp.com/collections/blabberTalk,
  method: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
    // Finds Id of most recent message displayed in the DOM
    var recentId = $('.message').last().data('id');
    var prevMostRecent = 0;
    var newMostRecent = [];
    jQuery.each(data, function(idx,el){
      if (el._id === recentId) {
        // if one of the messages on the server has an Id equal to
        // one of the messages in the DOM, it saves its index in a var
        prevMostRecent = idx;
      }
    });
    jQuery.each(data, function(idx,el){
      if (idx < prevMostRecent) {
        // if there are messages on the server with a lower index than
        // the most recent message in the DOM, it pushes them to a new
        // array. Basically, creates a new array of any messages newer
        // than the last one displayed in the DOM.
        newMostRecent.push(el);
      }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < newMostRecent.length; i++) {
      console.log(newMostRecent[i]);
      if (newMostRecent[i]._id === $('.message').last().data('id')) {
        // My attempt at trying to remove the last DOM message from
        // the array of newer messages. My main issue was that this
        // whole function would keep appending the most recent message
        // over and over again.
        var result = _.without(newMostRecent, newMostRecent[i]);
        console.log('MESSAGE TO BE EXCLUDED: ', newMostRecent[i]);
        // If the array of newer messages contained the most recent
        // DOM message, it removes it and sends it to be appended.
        page.appendNewestMessages(result);
      }
    }
    // If the array of newer messages DOESN'T contain the most recent
    // DOM message, it just sends the whole array normally.
    page.appendNewestMessages(newMostRecent);
  },
  error: function (err) {

  }
});
}
```

Here is the append function:

```
appendNewestMessages: function(messagesToAppend) {
console.log(messagesToAppend.reverse());

_.each(messagesToAppend.reverse(), function(el, idx, arr) {
  var newMessage = {
    content: el.content,
    timestamp: el.timestamp,
    author: el.author,
    userIcon: el.userIcon
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: page.url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: newMessage,
    success: function (data) {
      page.addOneMessageToDOM(data);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log("error ", err);
    }

  });
})
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how to get the most recent messages from a server and append them to the DOM without any repeats? This has been driving me nuts.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: don't delete the question, i am making answer

Comment: heh ^) looks like for me its working normal...:D (iam implemented my own page.* functions).. lets see...

Comment: u dont get last messages if u send one before fetching. :D u should rewrite server. it must send to you X messages after id ID. But not always a bunch of last X messages available